# iOS orientation change not working also UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification not received

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, orientation, rotation

I am quite new to iOS and I am trying desperately to get orientation changes working in my app. After researching here's what I do:

In my app I have a NavigationController managing seven UIViewController subclasses.

In the projects summary tab I activated all 4 device orientations.

Each UIViewcontroller subclass has a xib file, all xib files have "autoresize subviews" activated.

The UIViewController subclasses all have:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight );
}
```

they also all have:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

and:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

implemented with an NSLog(...) statements (never printed, debugger also never entering these methods).

Also I was trying to use:

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

BOOL getOrientationUpdates = [[UIDevice currentDevice] isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
NSLog(@"will receive orientation notifications: %@", getOrientationUpdates?@"YES":@"NO");

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

with

`-(void)orientationChanged: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSLog(@"orientationChanged");
}`

and

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` 
respectively.

when I do `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` etc. in the AppDelegate's `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`
 method, orientationChanged: is called once on startup but never again however I rotate the device, when I do it in one of the UIViewController subclasses it is never called!

So far, all I want to achieve is getting orientation notifications to rotate an UIImageView and UIImage (without any layout changes in the different orientations).

```
UIDeviceOrientation o = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
```

always returns `UIDeviceOrientationPortrait`

It might be that I missed something in the docs or on stackoverflow, but I obviously cannot figure out what I need to do/add to get it working in my setup. also I am quite new to stackoverflow, so I hope my post is not violating any platform conventions.

Any help/hints are greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

EDIT: 
getOrientationUpdates is always YES, which appears strange to me as the notification callback selector is never called when I rotate it!

EDIT: in my AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I am doing:

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.regScreenController = [[RegistrationScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationScreenController" bundle:nil];

navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.regScreenController];

[navCtrl setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
self.window.rootViewController = self.regScreenController;
[self.window addSubview:navCtrl.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Answer (score 5):

See if you are setting the `self.window.rootViewController` in your `AppDelegate's` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: method, because if you're adding only subviews to the window the orientation change notification does not fire.

Comment: thanks for your answer! if you look at my edit, I am setting the rootViewController, am I doing it the wrong way maybe relating to the UINavigationController? still stuck on what I am missing...

Comment: or phrasing it differently: if the problem is related to the rootViewController, if the UINavigationController is initialized with a rootViewController and I set the UINavigationController as a subView to the window, is it correct to also set the UINavigationController's rootViewController as the window's rootViewController or what is the right way to connect things here in order to get orientation change notifications? thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think so, you shouldn't add any subviews to the window. Just set the rootViewController and everything else in the hierarchy should start from the rootViewController, even if it's a UINavigationController, but definitely no subviews added to the window.

Comment: thanks again. I commented ou the line with the call to addSubview so I'm setting no subviews anymore as you recommended and I set navCtrl itself as the rootViewController with `self.window.rootViewController = navCtrl;`. still no change in behavior, no notification or callback for orientation change triggered :( am I still doing something wrong in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? Any ideas? Do I need to subclass UINavigationController and register it as the orientation notification receiver? I don't see in the documentation that this would be necessary..

Comment: The fastest check is to create a brand new project and see if it works, then look if there's is a difference with yours somewhere. Also make sure that the rootViewController (or the one inside) implements correctly `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`. In any way there isn't anything specific to configure more than you have done...

Comment: yes, I will have time to create a blank project with similar setup for comparison not before this evening. regarding `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, as navCtrl is my rootViewController now, this would mean that I have to create a subclass of UINavigationController and override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and set an instance of the subclass of this as rootViewController? I will test this and post the answer here

Comment: No the `UINavigationController` should pass it through... It won't pass it if you subclass it and support only one mode i think

Comment: correct, subclassing and overriding `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` did not help. I just don't think a blank project will help more, because to the point where I initialize things in the AppDelegate and show my RegsitrationScreenController (which does not do much itself) there's not more code involved, but I will give it a try asap. annoying as this is so common stuff and I don't get it working. if other suggestions, let me know! thanks so far, I'll post the update after setting up a test project for it!

Comment: or if anyone who ever used a UINavigationController to handle some UIViewControllers without tabbarcontroller or anything else could show me, how he got orientation change notifications working, it might also help a lot. I am asking this, as it should be a standard scenario, but I couldn't find example code with orientation handling for this setup. thanks

Comment: I was setting a subview in the UIWindow - changed it so I add the rootviewcontroller instead and now its fine. Thanks :)